# How to patch method ''.join using the mock library

Tags: python, mocking

To create a unit test of a given function, I need to patch `''.join(...)`.

I've tried many ways to do this (using the [mock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) library) but I just can't get it to work even though I have some experience creating unit tests with that library.

The first issue to arise is that `str` is a built-in class thus it can't be mocked. A [post by William John Bert](http://williamjohnbert.com/2011/07/how-to-unit-testing-in-django-with-mocking-and-patching/) shows how to deal with this (`datetime.date` in his case). There is also a possible solution in the ["Partial mocking" section](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#partial-mocking) of the library's official documentation.

The second issue is `str` isn't really used directly. Instead, method `join` of literal `''` is called. So, what should the path to patch be?

None of these options worked:

- `patch('__builtin__.str', 'join')`
- `patch('string.join')`
- `patch('__builtin__.str', FakeStr)` (where `FakeStr` is a subclass of `str`)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, because it is not possible to set attributes on built-in classes:

```
>>> str.join = lambda x: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'str'
```

and you cannot patch `str`, since `''.join` uses a literal, and thus the interpreter will **always** create a `str`, no matter how you try to replace `str` in `__builtin__`.

You can see this if you read the bytecode generated:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def test():
...     ''.join([1,2,3])
... 
>>> dis.dis(test)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('')
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (join)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
              9 LOAD_CONST               3 (2)
             12 LOAD_CONST               4 (3)
             15 BUILD_LIST               3
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             21 POP_TOP             
             22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             25 RETURN_VALUE
```

The bytecode is generated at *compile* time, and, as you can see, the first `LOAD_CONST` loads `''` which is a `str`, no matter how you change the value of `str` at runtime.

What you *can* do, is use a wrapper function which can be mocked, or avoid using literals.
For example using `str()` instead of `''` allows you to `mock` the `str` class with a subclass that implements the `join` method how you want(even though this may affect too much code and may not be feasible depending on the modules you use).

Comment: Nice way to "peek under the hood"! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you're feeling incredibly lucky, you can inspect and patch the string consts in the code object:

```
def patch_strings(fun, cls):
    new_consts = tuple(
                  cls(c) if type(c) is str else c
                  for c in fun.func_code.co_consts)

    code = type(fun.func_code)

    fun.func_code = code(
           fun.func_code.co_argcount,
           fun.func_code.co_nlocals, 
           fun.func_code.co_stacksize,
           fun.func_code.co_flags,
           fun.func_code.co_code,
           new_consts,
           fun.func_code.co_names,
           fun.func_code.co_varnames,
           fun.func_code.co_filename,
           fun.func_code.co_name,
           fun.func_code.co_firstlineno,
           fun.func_code.co_lnotab,
           fun.func_code.co_freevars,
           fun.func_code.co_cellvars)

def a():
    return ''.join(['a', 'b'])

class mystr(str):
    def join(self, s):
        print 'join called!'
        return super(mystr, self).join(s)

patch_strings(a, mystr)
print a()      # prints "join called!\nab"
```

Python3 version:

```
def patch_strings(fun, cls):
    new_consts = tuple(
                   cls(c) if type(c) is str else c
                   for c in fun.__code__.co_consts)

    code = type(fun.__code__)

    fun.__code__ = code(
           fun.__code__.co_argcount,
           fun.__code__.co_kwonlyargcount,
           fun.__code__.co_nlocals, 
           fun.__code__.co_stacksize,
           fun.__code__.co_flags,
           fun.__code__.co_code,
           new_consts,
           fun.__code__.co_names,
           fun.__code__.co_varnames,
           fun.__code__.co_filename,
           fun.__code__.co_name,
           fun.__code__.co_firstlineno,
           fun.__code__.co_lnotab,
           fun.__code__.co_freevars,
           fun.__code__.co_cellvars)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's really no way to do this that will work with string literals, as these always use the built-in `str` class, which is, as you have found, not patchable in this fashion.

Of course, you could write a function `join(seq, sep='')` that you use in place of `''.join()` and patch that, or a `str` subclass class `Separator` that you always use to explicitly construct strings that will be used for `join` operations (e.g. `Separator('').join(....)`). These workarounds are kind of ugly, but you can't patch the method otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm patching the variable inside the module I'm testing. I don't like the idea because I'm changing my code to fit the test but it works.

## tests.py

```
import mock

from main import func


@mock.patch('main.patched_str')
def test(patched_str):
    patched_str.join.return_value = "hello"

    result = func('1', '2')

    assert patched_str.join.called_with('1', '2')
    assert result == "hello" 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

## main.py

```
patched_str = ''

def func(*args):
    return patched_str.join(args)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is tricky a little but it works for most of cases.
It doesn't use the mock library, BTW. The advantage of my solution is that you keep using `''.join` without ugly modifications.

I found this approach when I had to run code written for Python3.3 in Python3.2 (it replaced `str(...).casefold` with `str(...).lower`)

Say you have this module:

```
# my_module.py

def my_func():
    """Print some joined text"""
    print('_'.join(str(n) for n in range(5)))
```

There's a unittest example for testing it. Note that it's written for Python 2.7, but can be easily modified for Python 3 (see comments):

```
import re
from imp import reload  # for Python 3

import my_module


class CustomJoinTets(unittest.TestCase):
    """Test case using custom str(...).join method"""
    def setUp(self):
        """Replace the join method with a custom function"""
        with open(my_module.__file__.replace('.pyc', '.py')) as f:
            # Replace `separator.join(` with `custom_join(separator)(`
            contents = re.sub(r"""(?P<q>["'])(?P<sep>.*?)(?P=q)[.]join\(""",
                              r"custom_join(\g<q>\g<sep>\g<q>)(",
                              f.read())

        # Replace the code in the module
        # For Python 3 do `exec(contents, my_module.__dict__)`
        exec contents in my_module.__dict__

        # Create `custom_join` object in the module
        my_module.custom_join = self._custom_join

    def tearDown(self):
        """Reload the module"""
        reload(my_module)

    def _custom_join(self, separator):
        """A factory for a custom join"""
        separator = '+{}+'.format(separator)
        return separator.join

    def test_smoke(self):
        """Do something"""
        my_module.my_func()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

And if you really want `mock` library, you can make `_custom_join` method return MagicMock object:

```
    def _custom_join(self, separator):
        """A factory for a custom join"""
        import mock

        return mock.MagicMock(name="{!r}.join".format(separator))
```